# Is there an OOTB way to check the assets of a payload (page) in a workflow- AEM6.5?

Tags: aem, aem-6

We have a workflow to request publication of the pages. I want to check all the assets on that page payload before publishing. The purpose is to have an option to publish any/all the assets on that page.

The functionality will be similar to the "Manage Publication". It gives an option to check the assets on the page for publishing.

Is there any OOTB feature that I can use?

Comment: Are you looking for an API or a UI to check for referenced assets?

Comment: @ImranSaeed Looking for an UI in the workflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AssetReferenceSearch](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/commons/util/AssetReferenceSearch.html) class. The AssetReferenceSearch#search method can find out the assets referenced on the page.